# Can you wrap text and use TextOverflow.ellipsis so that the text turns into ellipsis only when there is no space vertically and horizontally? Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am using Flutter

With just `TextOverflow.ellipsis`, the block looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Siotr.png) And without it, the text autowraps but there are no ellipsis when it overflows [(see here).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mStFD.png)

Is there a way to allow the text to wrap but use ellipses when it overflows. What I'm looking for is for the block to look like the second image but with ellipses at the end.

Btw the two images are different blocks, so don't mind the different dimensions.

Here is the code for the blocks:

```
final Widget linkBlockBody = Container(
      width: tileSize * width,
      height: tileSize,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(borderThickness),
      child: Material(
        shape: hasPadding
            ? RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))
            : null,
        color: blockBg,
        elevation: hasPadding ? 7 : 0,
        shadowColor: getContrastColor(pageBg),
        child: title != null
            ? Center(
                child: Text(
                  title!,
                  //overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: getContrastColor(blockBg),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : Container(),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `elipsis` tag with `maxline` tag. Use `maxline` to define how many lines you want to show before the overflow occurs. I think it will solve your problem.